# Monitor.TryEnter and Threading.Timer race condition

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

I have a Windows service that every 5 seconds checks for work. It uses `System.Threading.Timer` for handling the check and processing and `Monitor.TryEnter` to make sure only one thread is checking for work.

**Just assume it has to be this way as the following code is part of 8 other workers that are created by the service and each worker has its own specific type of work it needs to check for.**

```
readonly object _workCheckLocker = new object();

public Timer PollingTimer { get; private set; }

void InitializeTimer()
{
    if (PollingTimer == null)
        PollingTimer = new Timer(PollingTimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);
    else
        PollingTimer.Change(0, 5000);

    Details.TimerIsRunning = true;
}

void PollingTimerCallback(object state)
{
    if (!Details.StillGettingWork)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_workCheckLocker, 500))
        {
            try
            {
                CheckForWork();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(EnvironmentName + " -- CheckForWork failed. " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_workCheckLocker);
                Details.StillGettingWork = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Standard("Continuing to get work.");
    }
}

void CheckForWork()
{
    Details.StillGettingWork = true;
    //Hit web server to grab work.
    //Log Processing
    //Process Work
}
```

**Now here's the problem:**
The code above is allowing 2 Timer threads to get into the `CheckForWork()` method. I honestly don't understand how this is possible, but I have experienced this with multiple clients where this software is running.

The logs I got today when I pushed some work showed that it checked for work twice and I had 2 threads independently trying to process which kept causing the work to fail.

```
Processing 0-3978DF84-EB3E-47F4-8E78-E41E3BD0880E.xml for Update Request. - at 09/14 10:15:501255801
Stopping environments for Update request - at 09/14 10:15:501255801
Processing 0-3978DF84-EB3E-47F4-8E78-E41E3BD0880E.xml for Update Request. - at 09/14 10:15:501255801
Unloaded AppDomain - at 09/14 10:15:10:15:501255801
Stopping environments for Update request - at 09/14 10:15:501255801
AppDomain is already unloaded - at 09/14 10:15:501255801
=== Starting Update Process === - at 09/14 10:15:513756009
Downloading File X - at 09/14 10:15:525631183
Downloading File Y - at 09/14 10:15:525631183
=== Starting Update Process === - at 09/14 10:15:525787359
Downloading File X - at 09/14 10:15:525787359
Downloading File Y - at 09/14 10:15:525787359
```

*The logs are written asynchronously and are queued, so don't dig too deep on the fact that the times match exactly, I just wanted to point out what I saw in the logs to show that I had 2 threads hit a section of code that I believe should have never been allowed. (The log and times are real though, just sanitized messages)*

Eventually what happens is that the 2 threads start downloading a big enough file where one ends up getting access denied on the file and causes the whole update to fail.

How can the above code actually allow this? I've experienced this problem last year when I had a `lock` instead of `Monitor` and assumed it was just because the Timer eventually started to get offset enough due to the `lock` blocking that I was getting timer threads stacked i.e. one blocked for 5 seconds and went through right as the Timer was triggering another callback and they both somehow made it in. That's why I went with the `Monitor.TryEnter` option so I wouldn't just keep stacking timer threads.

Any clue? In all cases where I have tried to solve this issue before, the `System.Threading.Timer` has been the one constant and I think its the root cause, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Just curious, is `Details.StillGettingWork` (or its backing field) marked `volatile`?

Comment: @itsme86 `Details` is an instance class and `StillGettingWork` is an auto-property. Nothing is marked volatile.

Comment: Isn't something like this why mutexes were created for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548097(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @fernando.reyes Won't the mutex cause all the other worker threads to not be able to check for their own work? I thought this is why the Monitor was created. This is one worker trying to check for its own work and I need to make sure *it* only checks for work once.

Comment: @TyCobb The mutex would stop two processes modifying its value at once (that I think is what happened here), so you can control who runs at once and if someone else want to take it, will have to wait until the other is done. You can "try" to get the mutex, you don't have to wait until you can get it, if that's what worries you

Comment: " i.e. one blocked for 5 seconds and went through right as the Timer was triggering another callback and they both somehow made it in." -- I don't think that's possible with a properly implemented lock. I have a feeling your problem is that you have a different lock on every single thread, so the locks aren't actually doing anything. Make your lock static, or properly implement it so all threads use one instance lock instead of different ones.

Comment: @Quantic The lock is a readonly instance for that worker instance. It should be only locking for that worker. If I make it static, then other worker can't check/process work concurrently.

Comment: I'm guessing `CheckForWork()` is synchronous? Also, your `Monitor.Exit` should be *after* `Details.StillGettingWork = false`.

Comment: @InBetween No, `CheckForWork()` blocks until the work is done processing.

Comment: You describe the problem as: "I had 2 threads independently trying to process which kept causing the work to fail", so you think a single worker instance is running the method in 2 threads at the same time causing failure? It appears that your architecture is "Multiple workers, and each worker uses multiple threads"? For a single worker you can't have 2 threads "somehow make it" in to the locked section, and your lock looks fine. It's more likely that your `CheckForWork();` is sending the same work to different workers, not that a single worker has 2 threads inside the same locked section.

Comment: @Quantic Yes, also the time stamps dont make sense (although I'll amdit I dont fully understand the OP on this issue; he's saying not to pay too much attention to them and later on he's saying they are real). If it was the same worker calling twice `DoWork` the time stamps should be 5 sec off and they are not.

Comment: @InBetween, I just meant ignore the fact that they were the exact same down the millisecond. Quantic, I fully agree, but I have never been able to reproduce this. It only ever happens at a client. What confuses me is that the only actual thread I create is that damn Timer. I've poured over the code many times and I still cannot see the issue. I guess I am just going to have to spend an entire day hammering it and hope I can finally reproduce it.

Comment: "the following code is part of 8 other workers that are created by the service" - we need to see that code. "the only actual thread I create is that damn Timer." - you must have code that creates 8 tasks (or threads or whatever), so you must be creating more than just the timer thread, yes? Even if the timer was buggy and broken and somehow ran the callback on two threads simultaneously, your lock would prevent each from actually running `CheckForWork()` simultaneously. Your likely problem is that `CheckForWork` is not synchronized across the 8 tasks and sends the same work to two tasks.

Comment: @Quantic Processing is done in `CheckForWork()` if it found work. It doesn't get sent to another worker. That code is the worker. A worker gets created for each type of job when the service starts. The service just sits and each worker has its own timer. They are instanced, there's no statics, workers only get created once at startup.

Comment: You have 8 tasks running, right? Task #1 runs `CheckForWork()` and it says, "You process 1.xml", meanwhile task #2 simultaneously runs his own `CheckForWork()` instance, it says "You process 2.xml", at the same time task #3 runs his own `CheckForWork()`, and oops, it tells task #3 "You process 2.xml" and you get a failure. The timer is likely a red herring because 1) it will not call the callback twice in two threads and 2) even if it did your lock prevents the two threads from running the same code at the same time. At least add "worker#" to the logging to see what worker is processing what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Production stored procedure has not been updated in years. Workers were getting work they should have never gotten and so multiple workers were processing update requests.

---

I was able to finally find the time to properly set myself up locally to act as a production client through Visual Studio. Although, I wasn't able to reproduce it like I've experienced, I did accidentally stumble upon the issue.

Those with the assumptions that multiple workers were picking up the work was indeed correct and that's something that should have never been able to happen as each worker is unique in the work they do and request.

It turns out that in our production environment, the stored procedure to retrieve work based on the work type has not been updated in years (yes, years!) of deploys. Anything that checked for work automatically got updates which meant when the Update worker and worker Foo checked at the same time, they both ended up with the same work.

Thankfully, the fix is database side and not a client update.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in log you've provided that you got an `AppDomain` restart over there, is that correct? If yes, are you sure that you have the one **and** the only one object for your service during the `AppDomain` restart? I think that during that not all the threads are being stopped right in the same time, and some of them could proceed with polling the work queue, so the two different threads in different `AppDomain`s got the same `Id` for work.

You probably could fix this with marking your `_workCheckLocker` with `static` keyword, like this:

```
static object _workCheckLocker;
```

and introduce the static constructor for your class with initialization of this field (in case of the inline initialization you could face some more complicated problems), but I'm not sure is this be enough for your case - during `AppDomain` restart static class will reload too. As I understand, this is not an option for you.

Maybe you could introduce the `static` dictionary instead of object for your workers, so you can check the `Id` for documents in process.

Another approach is to handle the `Stopping` event for your service, which probably could be called during the `AppDomain` restart, in which you will introduce the [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx), and use it to stop all the work during such circumstances.

Also, as @fernando.reyes said, you could introduce heavy lock structure called mutex for a synchronization, but this will degrade your performance.

Comment: The AppDomain is used to load up the classes that do the actual processing the worker needs. The worker is generic. When it gets an update, it basically updates itself. Thanks a lot for your time. I am just going to have to find a day where I can hammer it and try to reproduce it through Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think that the code you've provided is thread-safe. Maybe, for some reason, two different workers got the same file to process.